# how to merging Jenkins jobs

Tags: jenkins

I am using Jenkins pipeline for our CI. In order not to make changes that will break the system, we copy the job to a "testing folder" in Jenkins, make the changes, test them to see that it is working, and than move the changes to the original job. Currently we are moving/merging the changes manually. Is their a way to merge the changes automatically ? some plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

You shoul ideally use jenkins-pipeline plugin (https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/) ,you can then save your configurations in a groovy file in a git repo , then in that repo you can have multiple branches and test those branches . When you think it works fine , you can merge it with the master branch . In this way you will not disturb any other jobs .